# Как управлять audio autoplay?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, аудио

У меня на сайте используется тег `audio` с `autoplay`. Как сделать чтобы `autoplay` срабатывал только при первоначальной загрузке страницы, а при переходе обратно с внутренней или при перезагрузке `audio` не повторялось?

Comment: cookie можно сохранять о том что аудио было запущено и на загрузке куки проверять, если было запущено повторно не запускать... тут уже в зависимости от риализации кода надо смотреть как сделать

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    if ($_COOKIE['audio']){
        echo '<audio src="URL"></audio>';
    }else{
        setcookie('audio',1);
        echo '<audio src="URL" autoplay=""></audio>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Может я что неправильно делаю, но не сработало.

Comment: Скорее всего неправильно. Скорее всего проблема в ф-ции setcookie(). Её нужно вызывать в самом начале, т.е перед выводом какого-нибуть текста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать без php

```
if(localStorage.getItem("Auth") != "yes"){
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = 'sounds/music.mp3';
    audio.autoplay = true;
    localStorage.setItem("Auth", "yes"); // запоминаем пользователя
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогло